# How do I pass a user input parameter to my cloud function?

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to learn about Cloud Functions for Firebase. I followed a tutorial to create an auth trigger and it worked great, but now I need to pass the `username` that the user wants to use to my auth event. How do I do this? Did I maybe use the wrong trigger here and instead needed an HTTP trigger?

```
exports.newUserSignup = functions.auth.user().onCreate(user => {
  console.log('user created', user.email, user.uid);
  const doc = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc();
  return doc.set({
    createDate: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    modifiedDate: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), 
    username: 'NEED TO FIGURE THIS OUT',
    email: user.email,    
    stat: 1,
    uid: user.uid,
    rowpointer: doc.id,
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to pass additional information to the `auth.user().onCreate` trigger, and unfortunately there is no way to trigger when the account gets updated.

Your current options are:

1. Create the document from within your application code after the account has been created.
2. Pass all information to a Callable or HTTP Cloud Function, and let that handle both the account creation and the writing to Firestore.

Both are completely valid options, so pick the one that seems most reasonable to you.

Also see:

- [How to complete login only after functions.auth.user().onCreate is finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60000617/how-to-complete-login-only-after-functions-auth-user-oncreate-is-finished)
- [Firebase Cloud Function - null user.displayName onCreate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60446655/firebase-cloud-function-null-user-displayname-oncreate)
- [firebase cloud function authentication: onCreate event doesn't contain displayName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48374855/firebase-cloud-function-authentication-oncreate-event-doesnt-contain-displayna)
- [Firebase functions user().onCreate: Pass parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62554225/firebase-functions-user-oncreate-pass-parameters)

Comment: The reason I'm trying to do it this way is because I want to try to protect my app from hackers as much as possible. I've read that some can now decompile an app to read my code, so I'm worried that they'll be able to manipulate it better that way if collection writes/reads are done from the client as opposed to safely doing it on the server. What are your thoughts on this?